# How to make a door opening smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a system where the doors open at a certain time of the day and they just teleport open so i was wondering how i can make them smooth(the script is in a empty gameobject) please help me ive spent hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quaternion.Lerp, use an asset **DoTween** to assist with *interpolation*, or create an animation using **animation clips** or the **timeline**.

Quaternion.Lerp:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html